# Convert datetime object inside Django ORM query

Tags: python, django

I want to filter queryset by year taken from datetime object, but using methods is not allowed with keywords. Thus, the following will raise an error:

```
a = Activity.objects.filter(start_date.year=2018)
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django has a [**`__year`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#year), so we can write this with *double* underscores (`__`):

```
Activity.objects.filter(start_date__year=2018)
```

Note that dates in datetimes can be "*timezone* sensitive", the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#year) mentions that:

> When `USE_TZ` is `True`, datetime fields are converted to the current time zone before filtering.

This can thus have *functional* impact, if for example a datetime is registered on the first of january 2018 00:01 in one timezone, then the this might not be in 2018 for another timezone.

Comment: Thanks! And what if I wanted to apply custom function - that Django does not cover for - to the keyword? Or is it a Pyton limitation that keyword can't be an expression?

Comment: @barciewicz: no you can not just specify a Python function for an ORM expression, you can try to use [Expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#expressions) and [lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups) to translate the problem, but if it can not be expressed with that/is infeasible to express it, you will need to do the filtering at Python level. A database typically does not allow loops, etc., or not without a lot of tricks.